# Declaring SparkContext type and accessing cassandraTable from spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have started a basic scala/spark/cassandra project, and am new to scala and spark. I am currently using the datastax `spark-cassandra-connector` to access my cassandra db in scala.

I have started with a simple storage class like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.datastax.spark.connector.ColumnSelector

trait Storage { }

class CassandraStorage(sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, keyspaceName: 
String) extends Storage {
  def rdd(tableName: String): Unit = {
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable(keyspaceName, tableName)
  }

  def write(tableName: String, columnSelector: 
com.datastax.spark.connector.ColumnSelector): Unit = {
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable(keyspaceName, tableName)
    rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspaceName, tableName, columnSelector)
  }

}
```

However, when I try to run this in the `spark-shell` I get the following error: `error: value cassandraTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext`

It seems the first two imports should make `cassandraTable` accessible on `sparkContext`. However this seems not to be the case for the type declaration when creating the class. Is there some sort of work around in scala?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of spark are you using? Why don't you directly read to dataframe?

Comment: I am using spark 2.2.0 and 2.11.8 for scala

Comment: Is that ok if you read as a datataframe?

Comment: @johnnydonna How are you deploying the app, locally in an IDE, pushing it to a cluster? The exception is essentially telling you that `cassandraTable` isn't available as part of the `sc` object meaning the connector dependency is missing when you try to run the app. If you tell us how you're introducing the spark-cassandra connector into your application it would help get to the bottom of this.